# Determining the account power automate runs under

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-online, power-automate

i have a SharePoint form, which gathers details into a SharePoint list. this list has a Power Automate flow which triggers an approval workflow which once approved will send out an email to designated mailboxes.

I need to modify the flow. How can i know which account the power automate flow is running under ? the person who created this flow has left the company and his account is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Power Platform admin access and if you know the flow name or flow ID, you can use PowerShell to get the flow owner details.

You can use this command to get the flow details: [Get-AdminFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powerapps.administration.powershell/get-adminflow?view=pa-ps-latest)

Refer below Microsoft official documentation for PowerShell installation and Prerequisites: [Get started with PowerShell for Power Platform Administrators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powershell-getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

For each flow there are owners and connections. Owners are the users who can modify the flow. Connections list the connectors (i.e. backend systems) used in the flow and the user account whose permissions will be used to access the system.

[image: Flow overview page]

The screen capture shows that the flow connects to SharePoint and to Office 365 Outlook and that it uses the permission for the rob@robwindsortest980.onmicrosoft.com account to do so.

Generally the user account associated with each of the connections will be that of the original author of the flow, however this can be changed on an action by action basis using the context menu for the action.

[image: Action context menu]

So to answer your question, you should check the connections for the flow to determine which user accounts are used to access the connectors used in the flow. If you need to change to user accounts used to access those connectors, you can do so using the context menu for each action.

Comment: Thanks Rob, i am not able to get to this stage itself cause i dont know under which account the flow was created.

Comment: OK. You'll need to get an administrator to go into the Power Platform admin center and share the flow with you. See Manage Power Automate flows (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/manage-power-automate) for details.